Modeling adjusted rates for individuals in multi-year studies with changing covariates
I am trying to estimate the probability of an individual leaving a company at least once over a multi-year study period. My data is organized by individual-company-year combinations in each row, with a binary outcome of 1 or 0 indicating whether the individual separated from that company that year. Individuals can be associated with multiple companies within a single year or just one company, and they may separate from none, one or multiple companies in each given year.
I want to calculate adjusted separation rates for different covariate subgroups (e.g., individuals working in rural companies or those aged 22-34). I created a binary outcome for whether an individual separated at least once (separation_once), but this causes misattribution of covariates during non-separation periods to separation events (i.e. if an individual is separated from a rural company but not an urban company, they still separated at least once, so urban will be associated with separation).
I recognize that the goal of calculating adjusted rates for each covariate subgroup (e.g., rural companies or age 22-34) is not exactly the same as estimating the probability of an individual leaving a company at least once over the study period. But, I need to make sure that the model accounts for the fact that multiple observations from the same individual are not independent, so I thought I could calculate the adjusted rate for each individual using Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE) and then average the rate for all of the individuals in the subgroup.
Does anyone know what type of model I can use to calculate these adjusted rates for each subgroup?
Thanks!
